# How to check hasMatch against a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate a form number against an array of regular expressions.

For now, I have this:

```
static bool isValidPhoneNumber(String input) {
    final RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'^\(\d\d\d\)\d\d\d\-\d\d\d\d\d$');

    return regex.hasMatch(input);
  }
```

The above works for a number in the format `(734)637-78673`.

But I want to match also for formats where the country code maybe 1 or 2 digits long

```
(1)498-5539867, (23)938-6738983
```

Answer (score 0):

(\d{1,3})\d{3}-\d*
The regex above should match all your phone numbers with a country code of 1-3 digits. I don't know how long the last row of digits can be so I added "*". You can replace it with the amount you need.

Comment: Sorry I am new to regex, how do I use it with the above function? ```final RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'^\(\d{1,3})\d{3}-\d*$');``` ??